# Add words to a border of a div - or something to that effect

Tags: html, css

I've created a codepen here:

https://codepen.io/aabarker/pen/WjQMjW

First image: The original image. When you hover over it, it changes.
Second image: My attempt at editing the CSS.
Third image: I'm trying to put the red bar from this third image ontop of the seocond image - both the original and the hover.

I tried with a border but it didn't work very well and I'm out of ideas. I'll be very interested to see how it is done, if it can be done.

The red bar should go on top of the image, not over the top of the image.

Thanks.

```
<!-- unedited original -->    
<div class="bord crossfd">

    <img src="http://stagehypnosisuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/35o-min.jpg" style="width: 300px;"></img>
    </div>
<!-- end of unedited original -->

<!-- my attempt -->
<div class="bord2 crossfd2">
    <h3 style="margin-top:-30px">Chapter 31</h3>  
  <img src="http://stagehypnosisuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/35o-min.jpg" style="width: 300px;"></img>
    </div>
<!-- end of my attempt -->

<!-- what I'm trying to achieve -->
  <div class="inline">
    <img src="http://stagehypnosisuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Untitled-3.jpg" style="width: 300px;"></img>
    </div>
<!-- end -->

/* CSS for original */

.bord{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

.crossfd{
background: url("http://stagehypnosisuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/35t-min.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
display: inline-block;
font:size: 0;
}

.inline{
  display: inline-block;
}

.crossfd img{
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.crossfd img:hover{
opacity: 0;
}

/* end of CSS for original */

/* My attempt by adding a border*/

.bord2{
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #CA3537;
border-width: 33px 0 0 0;
}

.crossfd2{
background: url("http://stagehypnosisuniversity.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/35t-min.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
display: inline-block;
font:size: 0;
}

.crossfd2 img{
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.crossfd2 img:hover{
opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: by ' the third image'  you refer to the one with video ? and also what red bar ? the one with ' Chapter 31 70min' ? it is very confusing what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a div with `position:absolute` to insert your text

```css
.container{
    position:relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
}

.text{
    width: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:red;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

p {
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
    <div class=text>
      <p> HELLO </p>
    </div>
    
</div>
```